# Xml serialize to object

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have to read some data from xml file and then need to store the converted json in the database. The class `DtoProcedureXml` mapped with xml attributes.

```
public class ProcedureManager
{
    #region Declaration
    private DtoProcedureXml procedure;
    private ProcedureDataManager procedureDataManager;
    #endregion

    public ProcedureManager() 
    {
        this.procedureDataManager = new ProcedureDataManager();
    }

    public bool SaveProcedureData(long procedureID)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        try
        {
            SetProcedureXmlData();
            isSuccess = SaveProcedureSummary(procedureID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonLogger.LogException("Failed to save procedure data");
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }


    private bool SaveProcedureSummary(long procedureID)
    {
        //saving the data to db
        return procedureDataManager.Save(new DtoProcedure { ProcedureID = procedureID, JsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.procedure), CreatedOn = DateTime.Now });
    }

    private void SetProcedureXmlData()
    {
        this.procedure = new DtoProcedureXml();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DtoProcedureXml));
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FileShareUrlBuilder.GetPath(Constants.Structures.PathType.XMLFILEPATH)))
        {
            object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            this.procedure = (DtoProcedureXml)obj;
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have some concerns with the function `SetSReportXmlData()` When I was debugging the `XmlSerializer` code takes few milliseconds, is it right to move that code in the `using` section?
Also please let me know if there is any efficient solutions than this logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some quick remarks:

- You don't need regions in a 50 line class. In fact, [avoid regions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53114/123339).
- Why do you store `procedureDataManager` and `procedure` on the class? Why not instead have `SetProcedureXmlData()` return a `DtoProcedureXml`?
- No need to shout: `XMLFILEPATH`. Constants should be PascalCased.
- `SaveProcedureData` can fail, so perhaps it should be named something like `TrySaveProcedureData`.
- You swallow the `Exception` and never even log it anywhere? Don't you want to know what has gone wrong and try to avoid the issue in the future?
- Avoid unnecessary comments like `//saving the data to db`. Your code should tell me that.
- I don't see the point of `SaveProcedureSummary` as a separate method: it contains one line and is called only once.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest not to recreate the instance of `XmlSerializer` each time, because it creates an assembly in memory that is not reused / unloaded. To avoid that, just create the instance as static field of the class or use something like a XmlSerializerCache.

see also: [XmlSerializer class may result in a memory leak and poor performance](http://dotnetcodebox.blogspot.de/2013/01/xmlserializer-class-may-result-in.html#comment-form)

---

- The value of `procedure` could be returned by `SetProcedureXmlData` and passed to `SaveProcedureSummary`. That makes it more clear the the methods have to be called in that order.
- The instance variable `procedureDataManager` could be readonly
- You could drop the `isSuccess` variable if you return the result of `SaveProcedureSummary` or false in the catch block.
- It would be more readable if the line in `SaveProcedureSummary` is splitted to 2 or 3 lines.
- The using is OK, but ther is no need to close the reader because it will be closed when the reader is disposed by the using.

Answer (score 3):

No need to say what @BCdotWEB and @JanDotNet have said but in addition there something called Dependency Injection- which is avoid creating an object each time in your constructor but give it as an argument. More details [Dependency Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178469(v=pandp.30).aspx)

```
 public ProcedureManager() 
    {
        this.procedureDataManager = new ProcedureDataManager();
    }
```

> should be written as
>
> ```
> public ProcedureManager(ProcedureDataManager procedureManager) 
>         {
>             this.procedureDataManager = procedureManager;
>         }
> ```

Note: once you use a using statement, you don't have to call a close method because using calls the Dispose method. for instance

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FileShareUrlBuilder.GetPath(Constants.Structures.PathType.XMLFILEPATH)))
        {
            object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            this.procedure = (DtoProcedureXml)obj;
            reader.Close();
        }
```

> should be written as

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FileShareUrlBuilder.GetPath(Constants.Structures.PathType.XMLFILEPATH)))
        {
            object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            this.procedure = (DtoProcedureXml)obj;         
        }
```

alternatively use try and catch so you can explicitly call the Dispose()
. More Details on that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx

You don't have to use this keyword in C#. You can just call the variable

```
procedure = (DtoProcedureXml)obj;
```

Also, you don't always want to catch all exceptions as you have done in SaveProcedureData() . Trying catching specific exceptions and alternatively you could log in exceptions you didn't anticipate.

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonLogger.LogException("Failed to save procedure data");
        }
```

Lastly, I rather refrain from names like this DtoProcedureXml as they don't give you knowledge of what the class does.